# Cannot download file from S3 with Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to access a file from my S3 bucket, but I keep getting a NullPointerException when trying to fetch it.

My application.properties file:

```
aWSCredentials.aWSAccessKey=theAccessKey
aWSCredentials.aWSSecretKey=theSecretKey
aWS.bucket=my.bucket.name.com
aWS.file.name=path/to/file/filename.zip
```

My config class:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class AppConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {

    @Value("${aWSCredentials.aWSAccessKey}")
    private String awsAccessKeyId;

    @Value("${aWSCredentials.aWSSecretKey}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3(){
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1.toString())
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .build();
    }
}
```

The class using the Amazon bean and trying to get the file:

```
@Service
public class ModelWrapper {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3Client;

    @Value("${aWS.bucket}")
    protected String bucket;

    @Value("${aWS.file.name}")
    private String awsFileName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setModel() {
        S3Object s3object = 
            amazonS3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, modelName)); // Exception inside here!!!
    }
}
```

The bottom of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.isStandardEndpoint(AmazonS3Client.java:3772)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.noExplicitRegionProvided(AmazonS3Client.java:3767)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.bucketRegionShouldBeCached(AmazonS3Client.java:4505)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.shouldPerformHeadRequestToFindRegion(AmazonS3Client.java:4501)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4426)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4390)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1427)
    at com.swipejobs.dispatchprediction.prediction.ModelWrapper.setModel(ModelWrapper.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

By looking at the debugger I can clearly see the method that throws the exception and why, the host in my request.getEndpoint() host is null:

[image]

However, I haven't been able to figure WHY the host is null. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious but been trying to figure this out all day. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Walk up your stack trace and examine the variable values, especially in your `ModelWrapper#setModel` method.